# Regular expressions adding ( and /

Tags: c#, asp.net, regex

I have created this regular expression:

```
Regex checkTranslation = new Regex(@"[^\p{L}\s0-9!?,.]", RegexOptions.None);
```

I want to be able to also add the signs: `(`  `/` and `)`.
So right now, I cannot write texts like these  (text) or text1/text2
I have tried to add this to my Regex:

```
Regex checkTranslation = new Regex(@"[^\p{L}\s0-9!?,.\(\)\/)]", RegexOptions.None);
```

But this doesn't seem to work

Comment: You first regex does allow `()`. Can you rephrase what you are asking?

Comment: The question is very unclear. What exactly do you want this pattern to match and what do you want it **not** to match?

Comment: Yes, sorry. I want it to match this:  (Hello)  and Hey/Hello

Comment: My first regex does not allow adding paranthezise, nor backslash or slash

Comment: What you think your first regex is doing?

Answer (score 5):

Inside the character set you do not need to escape certain characters, like ( and ). The following should work:

```
Regex checkTranslation = new Regex(@"[^\p{L}\s0-9!?,.()/]", RegexOptions.None)
```

Specifically, only the closing bracket (]), the backslash (\), the caret (^), and the hyphen (-) need to be escaped (and a special case is made for the hyphen where if it appears as the first character it is matched as a normal character).

Comment: You don't *need* to escape them, but if you *do* escape them it shouldn't cause any harm.

Comment: Mmmn, yeah, good point actually. In that case I'm not sure I understand the original question :)

Answer (score 1):

As your regex is inverted and most likely you will find some other characters that you also want to include, convert it to "whitelist" from "blacklist" and invert code that uses result of matching.

```
Regex checkTranslation = new Regex(@"[-a-zA-Z]")
```

Which will only match allowed words with hyphens.

Comment: I think it's already a whiltelist. It's a class of allowed characters, negated, and I guess OP is using it in the form of "if this negated whitelist matches *anywhere*, there's an invalid character, so fail". Your regex would need to be called against every character in the input individually to make sure it's a match.

Comment: @Rawling original regex is blacklist. It starts with `^` so it matches everything but prohibited characters. That is why question is unclear, original regex in fact will match `(` but OP says it doesn't, which most likely means he is also inverting result of the regex matching.